# linear combination of curves to match a single curve

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have a set of vectors (length of 50, essentially a set of curves) that i want to try to match another single curve(vector) and obtain the coefficients of each of the vectors in the first set to match the second curve. The coefficients need to be >= 0.0 . I.e, a linear combination of the first set of curves to match the single curve. Any help in which direction I should go would be helpful.

Comment: ambiguous terminology. What do you mean by curve(vector)? what kind of curve, spline or ??. An example of input and expected output would help a lot.

Comment: consider a spectral intensity curve for each of  a red green and blue light vs wavelength(x axis 400-700nm in some increment, i.e., 1nm). A target light (a curve of intensity vs wavelength) to match the three lights to the target light via a linear combination (obtain coefficients or each of the three lamps to comprise a fit to the target light)

Comment: Is the set of vectors a basis?  Is the curve you're trying to match in the span of that basis?  Alternatively, are you trying to get some sort of "best fit"?

Comment: I am trying to get a best fit of a scaled combination of one or more of the set of vectors to a single vector. What I want from the output of the calculations are the scale factors for each of the vectors in the set. The values must be >= 0 (no negative scaling, but 0.0 is a possible value)

Comment: May I suggest you to formulate your problem in a more mathematical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a set of curves
[image]
each of which you want to multiply with a scaling factor, so that it reproduces some target curve
[image]
as closely as possible.

This is easily done with a linear least squares approximation.

```
%# create some sample curves
x = -10:0.1:10;
g1 = exp(-(x-3).^2/4);
g2 = exp(-(x-0).^2/4);
g3 = exp(-(x+2).^2/4);

%# make a target curve, corrupt with noise
y = 2*g1+4*g2+g3+randn(size(x))*0.2;

%# use the `ldivide` operator to solve an equation of the form
%# A*x=B
%# so that x (=fact here) is x=A^-1*B or, in Matlab terms, A\B
%# note the transposes, A should be a n-by-3 array, B a n-by-1 array
%# so that x is a 3-by-1 array of factors
fact = [g1;g2;g3]'\y'

fact =

    1.9524
    3.9978
    1.0105

%# Show the result

figure,plot(x,y)
hold on,plot(x,fact(1)*g1+fact(2)*g2+fact(3)*g3,'m')
```

[image]

Comment: @user1925163: you're welcome. Please consider accepting the question if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

so thats what he meant!..
mathematica version..

```
x = Table[i, {i, -10, 10, .1}];
basis = { 
        Exp[-(# - 3)^2/4] & /@ x,
        Exp[-(# - 0)^2/4] & /@ x,
        Exp[-(# + 2)^2/4] & /@ x
    };
Show[
     ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]], #[[i]]}, {i, Length[x]}] ,
              Joined -> True , PlotStyle -> Hue [Random[]]] & /@ basis ]
y = Table [ 2 basis[[1, i]] + 4 basis[[2, i]] + basis[[3, i]] +
               RandomReal[{.5, .5}] ,{i, Length[x]}];
dataplot = ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]]}, {i, Length[x]}] ]
```

mathematica does not magically do least squares if you simply solve an underdetermined system, so find a least squres result explicitly:

```
coefs = FindMinimum[
              Total[(#^2 & /@ (Sum[a[k] basis[[k]] , {k, Length[basis]}]-y) )],
              Array[a, Length[basis]]][[2]]
Show[dataplot, 
      ListPlot[i = 0; {x[[++i]], #} & /@ 
            (Sum[a[k] basis[[k]] , {k, 3}] /. coefs), 
            Joined -> True]]
```

note if you want ot restrict the coefficents to be >= 0 as stated you can simply square the values in the formulation like this:

```
coefs = FindMinimum[
             Total[(#^2 & /@ 
              (Sum[a[k]^2 basis[[k]] , {k, Length[basis]}]-y) )],
             Array[a, Length[basis]]][[2]]
Show[dataplot, 
      ListPlot[i = 0; {x[[++i]], #} & /@
              (Sum[a[k]^2 basis[[k]] , {k, 3}] /. coefs), 
              Joined -> True]]
```

you will get predictably poor results if the actual best fit wants to have a negative value.